# Exclude one URL from HTTPS redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I want to exclude: 
http://domain.com/index.php?route=payment/redsys/callback 
This is what I have in .htacess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

that convert all url to https, how can I exclude the url to be converted to https?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, just replace `directory` with the folder directory that you want to stop beocming HTTPs.

```
RewriteEngine On

#Turns HTTPs on for everything, excluding directory
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/directory\/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]    

#Turns HTTP on for directory
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/directory\/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know the directory is a call to a function in Opencart
http://domain.com/index.php?route=payment/redsys/callback